# How do I get from JS array through JSON to a PHP array? (I'm at least halfway there)

Tags: php, javascript, json

I have a JS array, which I convert to JSON

JS

```
 mycode[0][0]=true
 mycode[0][1]="element1"
 mycode[0][2]=400
 mycode[0][3]=150
 mycode[0][4]=148
 mycode[0][5]=148
```

turned into JSON:

```
[
    [
        true,
        "element1",
        400,
        150,
        148,
        148
    ]

]
```

Now I push this to PHP

PHP code:

```
$decoded = json_decode($_GET["q"]);

$response=$q[0];

echo $response;
```

and it outputs a letter or a symbol as JSON was a string.

If I use $decoded[0][0] or $decoded[0] instead of $q[0] I get nothing...

What am I actually doing wrong?

What do I want? I need to have the same array I had in JS, just in PHP (the array will later be used in a PHP function)

Comment: What is $q meant to be, and where is it defined?

Comment: q is the JSON and it comes throught AJAX

[[ true,"element1",400,150,148,148 ]]

Answer (score 4):

Code:

```
<?php
$json = '[[ true,"element1",400,150,148,148 ]]';
$dec = json_decode($json);
var_dump($dec);
?>
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    bool(true)
    [1]=>
    string(8) "element1"
    [2]=>
    int(400)
    [3]=>
    int(150)
    [4]=>
    int(148)
    [5]=>
    int(148)
  }
}
```

Works fine here. Your problem must be somewhere else.

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.3.2 (cli) (built: Apr 27 2010 17:55:48) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
```

Comment: How did you get array (6) on the 3rd line? 
How can I call any of these values, are they values of an array called array?

Comment: They're just elements of an array. You just index it. `echo $dec[0][3];`

Answer (score 0):

How are you pushing your JSON to the PHP code. When you pass your JSON to the PHP back-end, you should use a library such as [json2.js](http://www.json.org/js.html) to encode the content:

```
var myJSONText = JSON.stringify(myObject, replacer);
```

You may also need to URL-encode the JSON if you are passing it using GET.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the AJAX part is fine since I get JSON - [[ true,"element1",400,150,148,148 ]] - as an output but only if the q array would be just characters and symbols (for example $q[0] outputs [ and $decoded[0] outputs nothing)...
As far as the JSON goes I tried JSONlint and it validated the code, so the conversion from JS to JSON is probably fine

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but in my opinion you need to read a lot more about the three things you want to use, specially AJAX and JSON